# Vue Error GitHub Pages: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, github-pages

I made a simple landing page in vue for my portfolio. It works locally but when I push it to github pages the page doesn't load and I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

The project vas generated with vite using vue 3.
My guess is the main.js which contains this:

```
import './style.css'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

I am out of ideas why this can happen so any feedback is appreciated.